# IBM JAX-RS 2.0 client and baseClients

Tags: jax-rs, websphere

We are using Websphere with her JAX-RS implementation. Our app reuse Client object (does not close it after every call). But in IBM JAXRSClientImpl is some baseClients hashMap (cxf use WeakHashMap) with is still growing. I didnt find other solution how to fix this except close the Client object. Any sugestions?

Comment: Hi Pavel, since it is a WeakHashMap, I would expect that entries would be removed when the clients are garbage collected.  So perhaps your app is continuing to reference the Client or WebTarget instances somewhere?  A heap dump should show what is referencing those WebClients.  You might also be able to reduce the number of WebClient entries by reusing WebTargets (not just the Clients).  HTH.

Comment: Apache cxf impl. use WeakHashMap, ibm implementation (com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.client.JAXRSClientImpl) use HashMap,sadly. Most of code is generated from OpenApi project, so WebTargets reuse is not posibble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previously posted assumption is correct that the use of a HashMap for client references was causing these refs to hang around until the client was closed, causing a potential memory leak.  The code in com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.client.JAXRSClientImpl has been fixed to utilize a WeakHashMap, which should address this issue.  The change has been delivered under APAR PH28458 (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PH28458).  The fix for this APAR is targeted for inclusion in fix pack 9.0.5.6.. So if you upgrade to version 9.0.5.6 or newer the issue should be resolved.